# How to pass the value of a postgres array to asyncpg connection.execute as parameter?

Tags: python, arrays, string, postgresql, asyncpg

I am trying to build a piece of code that uses [`asyncpg`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/index.html) to add content to a table in my postgres database, defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id              SERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    nested_field    varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    subfields       varchar(100)[]
);
```

From my POV, the difficult part is to save content into the [postgres array variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html).

The piece of code that I have built is the following one:

```
try:
    await connection.execute(query, thing_string, subfields_string)
    return None
except (Exception, asyncpg.UniqueViolationError) as integrError:
    # some other action
except (Exception, asyncpg.ConnectionFailureError) as error:
    # some other action
finally:
    # some other action
```

where the `query` it runs is defined as:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO my_table(thing, subfields) 
    VALUES($1,$2);
    """
```

and the `args*`

([here are the docs](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=execute) about `args*` argument for function `connection.execute` of asyncpg)

that will be put into the string as $1 and $2 are

1. `thing_string`, defined as `thing_string = "something"`
2. and `subfields_string`, obtained by running the line

`subfields_string = from_list_to_stringified_set(list_of_subfields)`

where

```
list_of_subfields = ["one, two, three"]
```

and the function defined as follows:

```
def from_list_to_stringified_set(list_of_subfields):
    """
    Given a list of subfields
    [ "subfield1", "subfield2", "subfield3" ]
    it returns
    '{ "subfield1", "subfield2", "subfield3" }'
    """
    subfields_string = ""
    for subfield in list_of_subfields:
        subfields_string = subfields_string + '", "' + subfield
    subfields_string = '{' + subfields_string[3:] + '"}'
    return subfields_string
```

so that the value of `subfields_string` results `'{"one, two, three"}'` (this result is achieved correctly by my code).

In order to work correctly, the query run on the database should be:

> ```
> # desired result
> INSERT INTO my_table(title, subfields) 
> VALUES('something','{"one", "two", "three"}');
> ```

However, as I try to run the script I get

```
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $2: '{"one", "two", "three"}' (a sized iterable container expected (got type 'str'))
```

So `connection.execute(...)` is not accepting my 2nd argument, `subfields_string`, having value `'{"one, two, three"}'`, because apparently it wants an iterable instead of a string.

But why?

The other arguments I am passing to `connection.execute(...)` as part of `args*` are also strings, so why the second argument is rejected and the first one is accepted?

And how can I change my code in order to get the `# desired result` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of strings as an argument.

```py
    query = """
        INSERT INTO my_table(nested_field, subfields) 
        VALUES($1,$2);
        """
    thing_string = 'something'
    subfields_string = ["one", "two", "three"]
    await connection.execute(query, thing_string, subfields_string)
```

The column `subfields` is a varchar array. The corresponding Python type for it is a list, as stated [in the documentation](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#type-conversion)

Comment: So I don't need to transform asyncpg input from `list_of_subfields` to `subfields_string`, sounds logic. I could not think that every person that needs to fill in an array field via asyncpg would had to implement a stringifying function... Thanks!

Comment: So asyncpg turned out to be smarter than you had thought, good news!